# How to use a checkbox in Materialize table

Tags: html, checkbox, materialize

I'm using Materialize and I'm trying to make a table that contains checkboxes. However, there seems to be a problem. A checkbox contained within a table doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if this a bug or if I'm not doing something correct:

```
<form action="#">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>My Label</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" /><label></label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

How do I make a checkbox contained within a table using Materialize?

http://jsfiddle.net/qa37un79/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You did not have an `id` for the checkbox and matching `for` attribute for the label:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" class="filled-in" />
<label for="myCheckbox"></label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xcmsLee9/1/

Comment: Seems like the label's HTML needs to appear immediately after the input's HTML too.

Comment: What if you don't want a label? The checkbox does not render :(

Comment: @Kokodoko leave the label empty?

Comment: That works if I use a single space as the label - but it still reserves space for the label which makes it hard to get the layout correct. If I set the label display to none in CSS, then the whole checkbox doesn't work anymore. By the way, I found the reason: the label renders the materialize-checkbox and materialize hides the real input element! This makes it hard to customize :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>*** Need text here ***</span>
</label>
```

Wrapping everything in a `label` element with a `span` right under it was the only way I was able to get my checkboxes to display.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small piece of code which will transform the data of nested array of objects into materialize table with check box , so if you dont want to view either of the column just select or deselect it  .

```
   // Using the Materilize css Check boxes change the functionality of the check bocx accordingly








var tab= document.getElementById("TransformTable");
//Get The No of Cols from the JSON data 
 var NoOfCols=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data[0]); //Insert the row for the table headings var row = tab.insertRow(0); //set the attribute row.setAttribute("id",0+"_row"); /**  * Loop for No of Cols and set the heading and append the CheckBox  */ for(var i=0;i<NoOfCols.length;i++){ var cell1 =row.insertCell(i); cell1.setAttribute("id","0_row"+i+"_cell"); cell1.innerHTML="<b>"+NoOfCols[i]+"</b>";

    $("#checkBoxDiv").append("<input type='checkbox' id="+i+" checked='checked' style='margin:10px;'/><label for="+i+" style='margin-right:10px;'>"+NoOfCols[i]+"</label>"); } /**  *Loop for the Table data  */ // Loop for the no Of rows for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++){ var row2=tab.insertRow(j+1); row.setAttribute("id",(j+1)+"_row"); // Lopp for the No of Cols in a row for(var k=0;k<NoOfCols.length;k++){ var cell2=row2.insertCell(k); cell2.setAttribute("id",(j+1)+"_row"+k+"_cell"); cell2.innerHTML=data[j][NoOfCols[k]];   } } /**  event Listener for the check Boxes  */ $("input").click(function(event){ var id = event.target.id; if($("#"+id).prop("checked")){ DisplayTable(id); }else{ HideTable(id); } }); /**  * [HideTable Hide the col of a table]

     */ function HideTable(id){ var ColId =id; for(var t=0;t<=data.length;t++){ $("#"+t+"_row"+ColId+"_cell").css("display","none"); } } /**  * [DisplayTable Display the col of a table]

     */ function DisplayTable(id){ var ColId =id; for(var t=0;t<=data.length;t++){ $("#"+t+"_row"+ColId+"_cell").css("display","table-cell"); } }
```